# C++ Trying to return a string of an array of doubles(kinda)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, double

my code is this:

```
double customer:: getAccounts()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {               
            if(Accounts[i].getBalance() != 0)
            {
            double x = Accounts[i].getBalance();
            return x;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Currently as you can see it just returns the first accounts balance and then finishes at that return point. However i was want to return each accounts balance in the one method to fit the program. This could be a string but im not sure how i would do this.

I tried:

```
string customer:: getAccounts()
    {
        string output;
        std::ostringstream s;
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {               
            if(Accounts[i].getBalance() != 0)
            {
            double x = Accounts[i].getBalance();    
            s << x;
            output += s.str;
            }
        }   
    return output;
}
```

But i get the following :

Error   2   error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and also :

Error   1   error C3867: 'std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::str' to create a pointer to member

Anyone shine the light on what i should do? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your method is more than a bit strange, but this is how to do it correctly.

```
string customer::getAccounts()
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {               
        if(Accounts[i].getBalance() != 0)
        {
            double x = Accounts[i].getBalance();    
            s << x;
        }
    }   
    return s.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) (`std::vector<double>`) as a return type.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function, rather than just referencing it.

Change

```
output += s.str;
```

to

```
output += s.str();
```

Of course a much better solution is to use a `vector<double>` type so that you can easily iterate over the values. As it is, there's not even a delimiter between the string values so you can't tell where one value ends and another begins.